# Позиционирование фигуры

Tags: c#, wpf

Пытаюсь по клику мыши (её координатам) отобразить прямоугольник, но он почему то  отрисовывается немного левее и выше относительно курсора, а не из под курсора, в чём проблема ?

Пробовал ещё и с линией, тоже присутствует смещение(

Цель отрисовывать из под курсора.

Координаты получаю так:

```
private void Window_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Point point = PointToScreen(Mouse.GetPosition(this));
    RisuemPryamougolnik(point.X, point.Y);
}
```

Отображаю прямоугольник по клику так:

```
private void RisuemPryamougolnik(double x,double y)
{
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
    rect.Height = 50;
    rect.Width = 50;
    // rect.Fill = Brushes.Aqua;
    rect.Stroke = Brushes.Aqua;
    rect.StrokeThickness = 1;
    canvas.Children.Add(rect);
    Canvas.SetLeft(rect, x);
    Canvas.SetTop(rect, y);        
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `PointToScreen` нужно использовать только если вы вычисляете позицию каких-то элементов расположенных за пределами вашего окна. Внутри вашего окна используется одна и та же система координат, поэтому переводить ничего никуда не нужно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Измеряйте позицию относительно вашего `Canvas`, а не относительно окна, ну и не нужно приводить координаты к экранным, т.к. они будут отличаться если включено масштабирование Windows (или при DPI отличном от 96):

```
Point point = Mouse.GetPosition(canvas);
```

или

```
Point point = e.GetPosition(canvas);
```