# Отображение дочернего окна под ListViewItem на котором произвели клик

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть ListView. Его Items - это строки, ItemTemplate которых состоит, в т.ч. и из CheckBox-a. Вопрос: как по установлению галочки в checkbox, отобразить дочернее окно под этим Item, вроде того как это делает ToolTip. Как получить координаты Item, активированного галочкой  checkbox в ListView, для вывода дочернего окна строго под ним.

[image: что то вроде этого. Синий прямоугольник и есть дочернее окно, под checkbox, которому поставили галочку.]

что то вроде этого. Синий прямоугольник и есть дочернее окно, под checkbox, которому поставили галочку.

Comment: Можете эскиз нарисовать того что хотите получить? Может вам нужно просто переключить шаблон контента CheckBox в зависимости от isChecked?

Comment: знаю, что в DataGrid есть <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate/>, еще есть контрол <Popup/>.

Comment: Ага, ну т. е. вам именно ToolTip и нужен: https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/5.3.php

Comment: Нет нет.. Tooltip уже прикручен к checkbox, отображает доп.информацию. A дочерняя форма по размещению похожа на tooltip, располагается под строкой, как бы подчеркивая строку с которой работаем на данный момент. На ней будут кнопки выбора действий, своя MVVM. И вызываться она будет после установки галочки на соответствующим checkbox. Я не знаю как именно расположить эту дочернюю форму под конкретным ListViewItem.

Comment: @АлексДронго, используйте @ для того чтобы обратиться, иначе я не получаю уведомления о комментарии мне адресованном. Ну а по сути — как я и писал в первом комментарии, вам надо переключить шаблон контента вашего CheckBox, пример здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/774441/218063 Также посмотрите дубликат к тому топику, если у вас меняется тип привязанной VM, то тот вариант будет удобнее

Comment: @АндрейNOP, я Вас правильно понял? Вы предлагаете не отлавливать координаты Items и вызывать дочернюю форму согласно этих координат, а просто изменить шаблон checkbox в шаблоне ListViewItem. Чтобы при установке галочки в checkbox-е отображался checkbox уже как бы с содержимым, которое в моей дочерней форме(другой DataTemplate)?

Comment: Шаблон контента CheckBox или DataTemplate самого ListViewItem, как вам будет удобнее

Comment: @АндрейNOP, я понял Вас. Может тогда сделать один шаблон ListViewItem, часть которого устанавить в Visibility="Collapsed", а при установлении флажка в Visibility="Visible"?

Comment: Можно и так, триггер подойдет. Если всё же хотите показывать окно, координаты мыши можно найти как указано здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/871246/218063 не забудьте к координатам мыши относительно окна прибавить еще смещение самого окна

Comment: @АндрейNOP, а я только хотел этот вопрос задать из спортивного интереса: почему нельзя как в WinForm: 
            int y = e.Item.Position.Y;

Comment: @АндрейNOP. Спасибо за помощь)

Comment: Можно, если сильно захотеть, найти родителя типа ListViewItem и вычислить его координаты по указанному примеру. Вот, кстати, что я говорил про экранные координаты: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10332880/6766879

Comment: @АндрейNOP. Значение Point то я получил, а вот как его прикрутить к window ни как не пойму. В WinForm было form1.Location = new Point(11, y + 77); В WPF ???

Comment: Left/Top смотрите